# How to convert multiline json to single line?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to convert a multiline json to a single line json. So the existing json file I have looks like this:

```
 {
   "a": [
   "b",
   "bill",
   "clown",
   "circus"
],
    "vers": 1.0
}
```

When I load the file, it comes in a dictionary and not sure how to strip blank spaces in the dictionary.

```
 f = open('test.json')
 data = json.load(f)
```

What I would like it to come out is the following:

```
{"a":["b","bill","clown","circus"],"vers":1}
```

Comment: `f.read().replace("\n", "").replace(" ","")`?

Comment: Did you try `print(data)`? I'm pretty sure it is already how you want it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the standard library [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) you can get:

```
import json

with open('test.json') as handle:
    data = json.load(handle)

text = json.dumps(data, separators=(',', ':'))
print(text)
```

Result:

```
{"a":["b","bill","clown","circus"],"vers":1.0}
```

Remark:

- `1.0` is not simplified to `1`, probably, because this would change the type from `float` to `int` at Python level.